# Bind UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber to @Published var from model data

Tags: swift, swiftui

My model data is looking like this:

```
@MainActor
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {

  @Published var myArray: [MyData] = []
  //...
```

Is it possible to bind the `UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber` to `myArray` so that the icon badge always shows the number of elements of that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this inside the main view

```
.onChange(of: modelData.myArray) { arr in
  UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = arr.count
}
```